# How to handle aliases for String arrays

Tags: java, arrays, alias

With the following code, I was wondering how to iterate through one String array, list2, **after** assigning it an alias of list, while changing the elements of list3 **without** changing the elements of list2:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"Hello", "Yay", "Okay", "Hungry", "Wheeee"};
        String[] list2 = list;
        String[] list3 = list;

        for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                list3[i] = "X";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(list2[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list3.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(list3[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It would output the following when I would want only the elements of list3 to be marked with the Xs:

```
X
Yay
X
Hungry
X
X
Yay
X
Hungry
X
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make a copy of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All lists are being modified because they all points into the same String objects. You have to make copy of `list` in order to keep it's original values. `String[] list2 = list.clone();`